# Right click not displayed on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic issue with an image.

Indeed, I can't make display a right click menu on the image (in order to see it in full display) :

I have just put a :

```
<img class="center" width="700" height ="381" src="./Image_Init_Scene.png"/>
```

Maybe the issue comes from other things in my HTML page (like jQuery etc).

Comment: You have several js scripts (`OrbitControlls.js`, `TrackballControlls.js`) that are preventing the `contextmenu` event. That's why the right click isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context Menu is being interrupted by an event handler somewhere in your code. While searching for `event.preventDefault()` works, this may be the long way out. Also this may not work if programmer is using `return false`

The easy way is to set a break point in the Debugger. Chrome offers a context menu breakpoint among others under Event Listener Breakpoints. Pausing the execution on modification will tell you, where the context menu is being manipulated.

For example, in your code, context menu is being used in two places postload.js and orbitcontrols.js. Orbit controls is preventing the context menu action with

```js
function onContextMenu( event ) {

 event.preventDefault();

}

scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', onContextMenu, false );
```

Removing this will restore context menu to original state.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the normal behavior of the `contextmenu` event is prevented somewhere in your code...

So you can find where it is prevented to remove this "protection"...
Or you can create you own custom context menu.

The event is still triggered, so you can use it.

```
$(".body_content img.center").on("contextmenu",function(){
    console.log("Context menu!");
    // Do what ever you want!
});
```

Comment: How to restore the standard contextmenu ? ,I don't want to modifiy JS scripts that I use, I just want to re-activate the standard one after all JS script that I have included

Comment: I think I read in your taughts... That is what I just edited... You have to look for `preventDefault()` on the `contextmenu` event somewhere in your JS.